# How to store image location in google app engine (Java)

Tags: google-app-engine

Sir I'm building an e-commerce site we want to store a multiple images in our site in .net I'm storing image location in Sql server but How it's possible in Google App Engine platform could you give any kind of example or form link to read and understand this topic

Answer (score 0):

If you have a few static images, you can add them to the `/war` folder in your App Engine project and deploy the project to the App Engine. You can add images directly to `war` or create a sub-folder `/war/images` if you have many images.

Then, in your HTML, you can simply reference the images as follows:

```
<img src="flag.png" />
<img src="images/us-flag.png" />
```

If you need to store a large number of images that change all the time (e.g. product photos), you need to use [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) or App Engine [Blobstore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/) to store your images.

Comment: Sir I know I can put images in war directory but I want it dynamically change the images l know to do with SQL servers and .net but I have no Idea about GAE so could you give some idea or form link to perticular this topic

Comment: I gave you links to Cloud Storage and Blobstore - this is where you start.